# Why am I getting a NullPointerException with an array of Strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string, nullpointerexception

I have made a function that sorts an array of randomly generated strings alphabetically. On line 64 of my code I always get a NullPointerException, even if I write if statements checking if the array has null values at certain indices. I have also made sure in main(), which creates the random array, that no index of the String[] array should be null. So what is the problem? Here is the code:

```
/**
    This program takes an array of random integers or strings and sorts them with selection sort and Arrays.sort() and determines which method of sorting is faster.
*/

import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortAssess{

    /**
        This function takes an unsorted integer array and sorts it using the selection sort method.
        Precondition: An array of int values.
        Postcondition: A sorted array of int values.

        @param baseArr This is the array that is to be sorted.
        @return The sorted baseArr.
    */
    static int[] selectionSort(int[] baseArr){

        int lastPlace;
        int maxPos;

        for(lastPlace = baseArr.length - 1; lastPlace > 0; lastPlace--){//Decreases part of the array to be iterated by one each search cycle.

            maxPos = 0;//Index of the largest element in the subarray.

            for(int i = 1; i <= lastPlace; i++){

                if(baseArr[maxPos] < baseArr[i])
                    maxPos = i;

            }

            int temp = baseArr[lastPlace];
            baseArr[lastPlace] = baseArr[maxPos];
            baseArr[maxPos] = temp;

        }

        return baseArr;

    }

    /**
        This function takes an unsorted String array and sorts it using the selection sort method.
        Precondition: An array of String values.
        Postcondition: A sorted array of String values.

        @param baseArr This is the array that is to be sorted.
        @return The sorted baseArr.
    */
    static String[] selectionSort(String[] baseArr){

        int lastPlace;
        int maxPos;

        for(lastPlace = baseArr.length - 1; lastPlace > 0; lastPlace--){//Decreases part of the array to be iterated by one each search cycle.

            maxPos = 0;//Index of the largest element in the subarray.

            for(int i = 1; i <= lastPlace; i++){

                int j = 0;

                while(baseArr[i].charAt(j) == baseArr[maxPos].charAt(j)){//NullPointerException
                    j++;
                }

                if(baseArr[maxPos].charAt(j) < baseArr[i].charAt(j))
                    maxPos = i;

            }

            String temp = baseArr[lastPlace];
            baseArr[lastPlace] = baseArr[maxPos];
            baseArr[maxPos] = temp;

        }

        return baseArr;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] randInts = new int[10000];
        String[] randStrings = new String[10000];
        String randString;//A single string to be added to randStrings, with random characters and length.
        long start, end, elapsed;//start of timer, end, and difference.

        //assign random values to randInts
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            randInts[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100000);
        }

        //assign random values to randStrings
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){

            randString = "";//initializes the string.

            //Create string at i of random length and with each index a random character
            for(int j = 0; j < ((int)(Math.random() * 40) + 5); j++){//creates a random length.
                randString += String.valueOf((char)((int)(Math.random() * 26) + 65));//generates ASCII code for character, which is converted to char and added 
                //to string.
            }

            randStrings[i] = randString;
            System.out.println(randString);

        }

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        selectionSort(randInts);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        elapsed = end - start;
        System.out.println("Selection sort of random integers took " + elapsed + " milliseconds.");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Arrays.sort(randInts);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        elapsed = end - start;
        System.out.println("Built-in sort of random integers took " + elapsed + " milliseconds.");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        selectionSort(randStrings);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        elapsed = end - start;
        System.out.println("Selection sort of random strings took " + elapsed + " milliseconds.");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Arrays.sort(randStrings);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        elapsed = end - start;
        System.out.println("Built-in sort of random strings took " + elapsed + " milliseconds.");

    }

}
```

Comment: And which line is line 64?

Comment: What happens when you try to debug it? Did you try to debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only initializing twelve of 'em.

```
//assign random values to randStrings
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
     // loop to deal with string array
}
```

You should consider using `randStrings.length` instead when dealing with arrays; that way, if you change the length of the array on a whim, you won't have this issue again.

```
//assign random values to randStrings
for(int i = 0; i < randStrings.length; i++) {
     // loop to deal with string array
}
```

Be careful there as well; I did notice a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in your while loop inside of `selectionSort`.  Double-check that you're iterating with respect to your bounds.

Comment: You should explain that because of the 12 init. there are null in the array and that's the NPE cause.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by @Makoto, You hava a declaration for `randStrings` to store `1000` Strings but you are only assigning `12` of them. The remaining are obviously pointing to null and therefore the `NullPointerException`.

**an advice**

whenever, you find yourself in such problems put `println` statements to get a better picture of the situation in which you are getting `exception`. The problem is half solved with this approach.